# Understanding direct self-reference in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I just started learning Haskell a few hours a go, trying to comprehend what this 
[The Fibonacci sequence](https://www.haskell.org/wiki/The%20Fibonacci%20sequence) does:

```
fibs = 0 : 1 : next fibs
  where
    next (a : t@(b:_)) = (a+b) : next t
```

`next` function is strange to me, it will eventually get some "invalid" input, like at first it goes like this:

```
next (0:1) = (0+1) : next [1]
```

but then `next ([1])` is not operable, since `t@(b:_)` has no input in it. So how does `next` work?

And my next confusion is `fib` itself, since it's suppose to be a Fibonacci sequence, I assume it will get `fibs = 0 : 1 : 1 : next fibs` after the first step, but then we will need to compute `next([0, 1, 1])` witch gives `(0+1): next([1, 1])` == `1 : next([1, 1])`, we get the initial element 1, so in `next([0, 1, 1])`, the first value of the list (in next fibs) will be 1, but attached this 1 to the original fib, we get `0 : 1 : 1 : 1` which is not Fibonacci sequence.

I think I misunderstood something, so how it actually works?

Comment: The reference back to `fibs` in the first line is referring to the *entire (infinite) list*, not just the two elements that were explicitly defined.  The first step isn't `next (0:1)`, it's `next (0:1:next fibs)`, and it evaluates to `(0+1) : next (1:next fibs)`.  Finite lists like [0, 1, 1] are never involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard way to define the result of a recursive definition is to approximate such value starting from `undefined` and unfolding the recursion from there as follows:

```
-- A function describing the recursion
f x = 0 : 1 : next x

fibs0 = undefined
fibs1 = f fibs0 = 0 : 1 : next undefined 
      -- next requires at least 2 elements
      = 0 : 1 : undefined
fibs2 = f fibs1 = 0 : 1 : next fibs1
      = 0 : 1 : next (0 : 1 : undefined)
      = 0 : 1 : 1 : next (1 : undefined)
      -- next requires at least 2 elements
      = 0 : 1 : 1 : undefined
fibs3 = f fibs2 = 0 : 1 : next fibs2
      = 0 : 1 : next (0 : 1 : 1 : undefined)
      = 0 : 1 : 1 : next (1 : 1 : undefined)
      = 0 : 1 : 1 : 2 : next (1 : undefined)
      -- next requires at least 2 elements
      = 0 : 1 : 1 : 2 : undefined
fibs4 = f fibs3 = 0 : 1 : next fibs3
      = 0 : 1 : next (0 : 1 : 1 : 2 : undefined)
      ...
```

If we keep going on we will approach the full sequence "at the limit", approximating it step by step. This informal argument can be formally justified through the Kleene's fixed point theorem.

Comment: To be clarify, so intuitively thinking, `fib` is the sequence `[a0, a1 ,a2...] (=x) ` which actually satisfies  `x = [0,1,  (next x)] `(in mathematical manner), and `next(=g)` is the function which actually satisfies `g([a,b0,b1,b2....])=[a+b0, g([b0, b1 ,b2...])]`, and such `x and g` exist and are unique, and can be obtained by approximation(by putting value in repeatedly), which is guaranteed by Kleene's fixed point theorem?

Comment: @CYC Roughly, yes. Both `fib` and `next` are defined by recursion, so technically one would need to apply Kleene twice, in the domain of lists (`fib`) and that of functions from lists to lists (`next`). Above I showed the approximation in the list domain more precisely, while I did not proceed with the same level of detail for `next`, and instead worked using intuition. Indeed, even ignoring fixed points, you can get some result by simply expanding the definitions of `fibs` and `next`, pretending their defining recursive equations just hold.

Answer (score 0):

The `next` function actually generates the `fibs` - so it won't call `next [0, 1, 1]` it will call `next (0 : 1 : 1 : next rest)`.

There is what is going on in pictures:

```
fib = 0 : 1 : not-yet-evaluated-part
```

---

```
fib = 0 : 1 : [+] : not-yet-evaluated-part
      ^   ^    |
      *---*----* (applying next to fib)
```

---

```
fib = 0 : 1 : 1 : [+] : not-yet-evaluated-part
          ^   ^    |
          *---*----* (next calls itself)
```

---

```
fib = 0 : 1 : 1 : 2 : [+] : not-yet-evaluated-part
              ^   ^    |
              *---*----* (etc)
```

The `next` is the "railroad-builder train" requiring some initial rails to run (`0 : 1 :` ...).

Because there is to `[]`-end of list placed nowhere in the fibs list, it will go infinite.

However, I recommend you to start from less obscure things - for instance, you should try understand lists alone.

Comment: the recursive call will not get the entire list but only a tail. and there's only one recursive call not two.